# Using pragma push in precompiled header with Clang without pop

Tags: c++, clang, precompiled-headers

In my codebase, I have an include file (`MyBaseDefinitions.h`) that does a `pragma diagnostic push` followed by disabling a lot of warnings. If you want to re-enable those warnings, you simply include another header afterwards that does pragma diagnostic pop (`EndMyBaseDefinitions.h`).

This seems to work fine except on Clang when putting `MyBaseDefinitions.h` in the precompiled header. It appears that the diagnostic 'stack' is lost when it's in a precompiled header. So let's say I have `MyPrecompiledHeader.h` and it has:

`#include "MyBaseDefinitions.h" // does the pragma diagnostic push`

And then in my demo file I do:

```
#include "MyPrecompiledHeader.h"

#include "HeaderExample1.h" // This file has some warnings in it that we don't care about
#include "EndMyBaseDefinitions.h" // Re-enable warnings

// ...
```

I'll get a warning:

`error : pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Werror,-Wunknown-pragmas]`

Is this a known issue? Obviously ideally I wouldn't have to do any warning disabling at all, but let's try to ignore that detail for now if possible.

--Joel

Comment: My uneducated guess is that nobody anticipated that you would be doing this :)